# Is there any work around for this bug(https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-55724) join plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Join plugin does not work after migration to new Jenkins version 2.161. Is there any workaround for this bug(https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-55724)?

Comment: Have you looked at migrating to pipelines?    Parallel stages with Declarative Pipeline -  https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/  Your question could explain what you are trying to achieve if you want  more constructive help.

Comment: That's a great suggestion but it would require me to test the whole pipeline again. I used JobFanin plugin instead to build the old pipelines again. It worked.